# I cannot install dayjs library on new angular app

Tags: dayjs

I'm new to angular and I'm currently making some tutorials and I ran onto some dependency tree issue when I try to install **dayjs** library. I looked for an answer and I assume that the library should be updated.

I run the following command :
`npm install --save angular-dayjs dayjs`
and the result I got is

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: test-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~13.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^11.2.7" from angular-dayjs@0.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/angular-dayjs
npm ERR!   angular-dayjs@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I assume that the author of the library should rebuild the it against latest angular/common but
is there any chance to solve this issue on my own?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need `angular-dayjs` you can work directly with `dayjs`

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! You are great! It worked.